# Multiple file uploads using formset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

models.py

```
class Album(models.Model):
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    name_content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And Function is here

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    upload_dir = os.path.join('uploads', 'resource')
    return os.path.join(upload_dir, filename)
```

forms.py

```
class Albumform(forms.Form):
    name_content = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    file_upload = forms.FileField( 'please select' )
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
def viewalbum(request):    
    AlbumFormSet = formset_factory(Albumform, extra=3, max_num=10,)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AlbumFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            albumvalue = Album()
            albumvalue.name_content = request.POST.get('name_content', None)
            albumvalue.file_upload = request.FILES['file_upload']
            albumvalue.save()


            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('views.viewalbum'))
    else:
        formset = AlbumFormSet()
    return render_to_response('audio/test.html',{'formset': formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the html looks like this

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

The problem is i can only upload one file at the time. Give me solution to upload multiple file in the same time and saved into resource folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload multiple files, then you need multiple filefields. That is your option A. If you choose to go for it, create formset and use it to provide multiple file upload.

your option B is to use some kind of javascript widgets that make multiple file uploads possible.

Comment: please can you tell me little more about formset. for my above question how can i add formset then?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/. You might need different database structure for it though. Keep Album name in one class and files in another, which is linked by (multiple)foreign key to album. Then you can have same images in several albums. Rest of it is all descibed in the django link i added.

Comment: i tried but its return this error[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']

Comment: Take a look at this part of the page i previously sent: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform